# Adding 'active' class to Nuxt.js Bootstrap

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt.js and I wish to add the active class to a nav item. The following code is what I have come up with for the navigation:

```
<div>
  <b-navbar type="dark" variant="dark">
    <b-navbar-nav>
      <b-nav-item href="/">Home</b-nav-item>
      <b-nav-item href="/locations">Locations</b-nav-item>
    </b-navbar-nav>
  </b-navbar>
</div>
```

The question is, how can I use the active class?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `active` to your `b-nav-item`

```
<div>
  <b-nav>
    <b-nav-item active>Active</b-nav-item>
    <b-nav-item>Link</b-nav-item>
    <b-nav-item>Another Link</b-nav-item>
    <b-nav-item disabled>Disabled</b-nav-item>
  </b-nav>
</div>
```

Comment: which is fine @brooksrelyt, but how to change the active status on route change in Nuxt?

Comment: Maybe try this something like this `<b-link to="/" exact />`, info found here: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/router-links/

Comment: `<b-nav-item active><b-link to="/" exact>Home</b-nav-item>` ?

Comment: Not sure I assume it's something like `<b-nav-item href="/" exact>Home</b-nav-item>` but the active-class area of that link should help